# Flutter Application localization approaches

Tags: mobile, dart, localization, flutter

This article shows 2 approaches for implementing the localization for Flutter apps

https://flutter.io/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization

One is using creating files for the l10n and other is simple and direct.

I see that the l10n with the `intl` dependency is little bit complicated and frustrating for creating files for each lang and 2 terminal commands
and if I need to add a new term I have to go through the commands and files creations.

But anyway both work.

Is one is better than the other?

Answer (score 0):

The variant using the `intl` package makes it easy to work with translate https://translate.google.com/toolkit.

If you want to use the same code for a web client tree-shaking will work better with this approach for smaller download sizes. I don't think this makes much difference in Flutter.

The downside as you mentioned is, that it needs more boilerplate to get going.

Comment: so can i use the easy approach without going with the arb one as it will be easier to add new terms without that hasseling ... any downsides for the easy one?

Comment: I don't think there are specific downsides. It shouldn't be too hard to switch from one to the other in case you decide that you want to switch.

Comment: As of December 4, 2019, Google Translator Toolkit has shut down.